# set label position based on neighbor label

Tags: c#, .net, position, label

supposing that I have two labels with variables text.

For example:

```
label1.Text = "foo";
label2.Text = "baa";
```

Form output:

```
________________
|               |    
|foo baa        | 
|______________ |
```

other example:

```
label1.Text = "fooooo";
label2.Text = "baaaa";
```

Form output:

```
    ________________
    |               |    
    |fooooo baaaa   | 
    |______________ |
```

I tried it:

```
  label2.Location = new Point
            {
                X = label1.Location.X + label2.Location.X,
                Y = label1.Location.Y
            };
```

I imagined that the space was sufficient. But label2 hide label1 if the text is larger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `label1.Right` instead:

```
label2.Location = new Point(label1.Right, label2.Top);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a FlowLayoutPanel which automatically positions its child controls next to each other.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|FlowLayoutPanel                            |
| +------+ +------+                         |
| |Label1| |Label2|                         |
| +------+ +------+                         |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|FlowLayoutPanel                            |
| +--------------------+ +------+           |
| |LabelWithLotsOfText1| |Label2|           |
| +--------------------+ +------+           |
+-------------------------------------------+
```